# Why doesn't dpkg -L show files under /usr/lib for this package?

Tags: ppa, directory-structure

I've installed the `golang-1.8` package from [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~gophers/+archive/ubuntu/archive) and I can see that it's installed some stuff under `/usr/lib`, namely:

```
/usr/lib$ ls -lha go-1.8/
total 48K
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4,0K Abr 24 01:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 190 root root  32K Abr 24 01:39 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4,0K Abr 24 01:39 bin
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   35 Abr 10 01:59 doc -> ../../share/doc/golang-1.8-doc/html
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   45 Abr 10 01:59 favicon.ico.gz -> ../../share/doc/golang-1.8-doc/favicon.ico.gz
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root 4,0K Abr 10 01:59 pkg
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   22 Abr 10 01:59 src -> ../../share/go-1.8/src
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   23 Abr 10 01:59 test -> ../../share/go-1.8/test
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    7 Abr 10 01:49 VERSION
```

(these files are even listed in the PPA page)

However, running `dpkg -L golang-1.8` (even using `sudo`) returns only stuff under `/usr/share`:

```
/usr/lib$ dpkg -L golang-1.8
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/golang-1.8
/usr/share/doc/golang-1.8/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/golang-1.8/copyright
```

Has this got something to do with the fact that, while the package name is `golang-1.8`, it's installed stuff under `/usr/lib/go-1.8`? Or because this was downloaded from a PPA?

**P.S.: I'm running ubuntu 16.04 LTS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files created by package-specific installation-scripts are not listed.

From `man dpkg`:

```
dpkg-query actions
              See  dpkg-query(1)  for  more  information  about  the following
              actions.

              -l, --list package-name-pattern...
                  List packages matching given pattern.
              -s, --status package-name...
                  Report status of specified package.
              -L, --listfiles package-name...
```

From `man dpkg-query`:

```
-L, --listfiles package-name...
              List files installed to your system from package-name. When mul‐
              tiple package-name are listed, the requested lists of files  are
              separated  by an empty line, with the same order as specified on
              the argument list. However, note that files created by package-
              specific installation-scripts are not listed.
```